# Performance issues with AVAssetWriterInput (audio) and single-core devices

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording, avassetwriter

I'm having a strange performance issue with `AVAssetWriterInput` on single-core devices like the iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4. Basically, I have an AVAssetWriter with two AVAssetWriterInputs, one for video and one for audio. Roughly, it looks like:

```
AVAssetWriter * assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:videoURL
                                                        fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                           error:&error];
videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                      outputSettings:videoSettings]; 
videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

NSDictionary * audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],      AVFormatIDKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:64000],                     AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:44100],                     AVSampleRateKey,
                                    currentChannelLayoutData,                           AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                    nil];
audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                      outputSettings:audioSettings];
audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES; 

[assetWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
[assetWriter addInput:audioWriterInput];
```

There's also an `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` in there but I left it out for brevity's sake. I create one serial dispatch queue that I use for both video and audio writing. When I get a new video frame, I dispatch the job onto that serial queue, and when I get new audio bytes, I dispatch that job to the same serial queue. This way, most of the audio writing code doesn't happen on the audio callback thread (which would otherwise slow down the high-priority audio thread).

I'm able to write a video with audio successfully and it performs fine on dual-core devices. However, on single core devices, I find that there's a noticeable stutter on the device's display roughly every 500-700ms. I've tracked down the culprit to the following:

```
if ([audioWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData])
{
    if (![audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer])
    {
       NSLog(@"Couldn't append audio sample buffer: %d", numAudioCallbacks_);
    }
}
```

If I comment out the `appendSampleBuffer` for the `audioWriterInput`, then obviously no audio gets written, but there's no stutter in the actual display either. It's weird because all of this is happening **off** of the main thread. CPU/GPU times per frame are on the order of 4-5 ms, so it's not like the CPU/GPU are bottlenecked.

Another clue/curiosity: when I do write audio buffers, I get a saw-tooth like memory graph like the following:

[image: sawtooth]

It seems to me that the audioWriterInput is queueing up some buffers and then writing/releasing them.

One last hint is that it seems like the stuttering is less severe when I record as mono instead of stereo. Unfortunately, the sounds that come in are stereo, so when I do that, the sound is wrong. Either way, the stuttering doesn't go away completely so it's not really a valid solution, but might hint at the fact that stereo takes up more resources to handle.

Does anyone have any ideas on why writing audio with the `AVAssetInputWriter` causes the entire app to stutter? These devices obviously only have one core so all threads will run on that, but it seems strange that the main thread should stutter when CPU load is so low.

Comment: Hey, did you ever determine the issue here? Would absolutely love to know if you did.

Comment: Same here - would be quite curious to hear how you solved this.